# Linq and SQL Azure starnge behavior

Tags: linq, xamarin.forms, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm creating a new Xamarin Forms application and I use a Azure Mobile App connected to a SQL Azure database.

Here is a code I wrote to query a table :

```
IEnumerable<Club> clubs = await (from club in ClubManager.DefaultManager.ClubTable.CreateQuery()
                          where club.Nom.Contains(TexteRecherche)
                          select club).ToEnumerableAsync();
```

I randomly get the following exception :

```
The exception
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException occurred
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)    
  Source = <Unable to evaluate the source of the exception>
  Procedural Call Tree:
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__24.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.<RequestAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<ReadAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable.<ReadAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__8`1.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider.<Execute>d__7`1.MoveNext()
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   à EagleGolf.CourseEditor.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.<LitClubs>d__23.MoveNext() dans D:\Julien\MobileApps\EagleGolf.CourseEditor\EagleGolf.CourseEditor\EagleGolf.CourseEditor\ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs :ligne 107
build : `
```

It's very strange because I close and start again the application and it works again. It can work 2-3 times, then stop working, then work again.

My database contain only 1 table and this table contains only 2 records ...

Comment: Depending on what you are using for your data access, you need to configure it to be more resilient to data connectivity issues when operating with SQLAzure. For example, with Entity Framework there is a specific Execution Strategy configuration for SQLAzure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456835(v=vs.113).aspx  For other data retrieval options you'll need to take similar steps /w SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Club> clubs = await (from club in ClubManager.DefaultManager.ClubTable.CreateQuery()
                      where club.Nom.Contains(TexteRecherche)
                      select club).ToEnumerableAsync();
```

For `IMobileServiceTable` table, the above query would send the following request against your mobile app backend:

```
Get https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/{table-name}?$filter=substringof('{TexteRecherche}',Nom)
```

> Message=The request could not be completed.  (**Bad Request**)

I assumed that you could leverage [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and check with your code when invoking the related queries as follows:

[image]